# tkinter Error that occured when using list to create label

Tags: python, firebase, tkinter

I'm studying python lately, and now I'm working on tkinter and firebase.
I was making a timeline viewer that can be changed from a manager.

As I was making, I had to make a table of labels that is 5*7 size.
At first, I tried to make it like:
label12 = Label(...

But I thought that I could make it into list:
label[1][2] = Label(...)

I tested it on other code, and the first dimension list worked well, with the configuration working.
I could change the text of the label with:
label[1].config(text="test)

but, when I used it on the second dimension list, it gave me an error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'config'

This is a part of my code where the error occured.
when I changed the text from daylabel using config, it worked well.

```
def RegistClicked():
day = \['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'\]

    dayarray = ["월요일", "화요일", "수요일", "목요일", "금요일"]
    daylabel = [0 for i in range(5)]
    numlabel = [0 for i in range(8)]
    classnumlabel = [[0 for i in range(6)] for j in range(8)]
    for i in range(0, 5):
        daylabel[i] = Label(win, width=10, height=2, text=dayarray[i])
        daylabel[i].grid(row=4, column=i+2)
    for i in range(0, 7):
        numlabel[i] = Label(win, width=10, height=2, text=i+1)
        numlabel[i].grid(row=i+5, column=1)
    for i in range(1, 8):
        for j in range(1, 6):
            classnumlabel[i][j] = Label(win, width=10, text="value")
            classnumlabel[i][j].grid(row=i+4, column=j+1)
    
    global selectclass
    selectclass = strvar.get()
    classlabel.config(text=selectclass)
    
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(1, 8):
            dir = db.reference(selectclass +'/'+ day[i] +'/'+ 'class' + str(j))
            print(selectclass +'/'+ day[i] +'/'+ 'class' + str(j))
            classnumlabel[j][i].config(text=dir.get())
```

Everything was well until I hit the refresh button, which triggers the function above, would kill the program with the error saying that the dayclasslabel array is an 'int' object.

Comment: I started learning python only about a few weeks ago, so please understand if my code is not good.

Comment: `classlabel` is not even defined in the code you've pasted, so it's hard to help without knowing the context.

Comment: Also, I think you're confusing yourself with the predefinitions of `daylabel` and `numlabel` as lists containing ints, which are replaced in loops. Use `append` instead...

Comment: Check your code on the numbers in those `range(...)`, are they consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is caused by trying to call `config` on a zero integer.

Instead of "predefining" the lists full of zeroes, just `append` into them.

Additionally, don't use "magic numbers" and ranges such as `(0, 5)`, `(0, 7)`, then suddenly `(1, 8)` and `(1, 6)`, but name the values (or better yet, in the case of days you can just `enumerate` the list of day names.

You might be looking for something like this...

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk


def build_class_win(class_count):
    win = Tk()

    selectclass = '...'
    day_names = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']

    day_labels = []
    num_labels = []
    class_num_labels = {}

    # Build day labels

    for day_index, day_name in enumerate(day_names):
        day_label = Label(win, width=10, height=2, text=day_name)
        day_label.grid(row=0, column=day_index + 1)
        day_labels.append(day_label)

    # Build class labels

    for class_index in range(class_count):
        num_label = Label(win, width=10, height=2, text=class_index + 1)
        num_label.grid(row=1 + class_index, column=0)
        num_labels.append(num_label)

    # Build mapping of day/class labels 

    for day_index, day_name in enumerate(day_names):
        for class_index in range(class_count):
            reference = f'{selectclass}/{day_name}/class{class_index}'
            cls_label = Label(win, width=10, text=reference)
            cls_label.grid(row=class_index + 1, column=day_index + 1)
            class_num_labels[(day_index, class_index)] = cls_label
            # TODO: add firebase stuff here
    return win


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = build_class_win(class_count=7)
    win.mainloop()
```

The window looks like

[image]